# python kivy строение .kv файла

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        root = BoxLayout()
        left = BoxLayout() 
        right = BoxLayout()

        root.add_widget(left)
        root.add_widget(right)

        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```

Как правильно построить .kv файл, чтобы напрямую работать с виджетами root, left, right?

Пробовал:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
<ExampleApp>:
    left:
        Label:
            text: 'Hi1'
        Label:
            text: 'Hi2'
```

Тут выдает ошибку

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
<left>:
    Label:
        text: 'Hi1'
    Label:
        text: 'Hi2'
```

Здесь ничего не происходит.

Еще вопрос, в доках есть два обязательных класса: главный, наследуемый от App, который ссылается на класс самого приложения, и класс, наследуемый обычно от виджета, в котором пишется код.
НО
Большинство примеров работы с киви построены через 1 главный класс, в котором функция build ссылается на созданный в ее теле виджет, как это сделал я.

Что является более корректным и почему?

Или стоит просто создавать один виджет, и уже через .kv файл наполнять его надписями и кнопками, а не делать вложенные?

И можно ли запустить скрипт в режиме отладки, чтобы видеть все границы виджетов?

Comment: Вы вообще все делаете против логики Kivy! Вы должны создать макет UI, в котором будут описаны все виджеты и контроллы, а в python коде уже непосредственно работать с макетом: изменять свойства, подписи и т.п. А вы создали почти пустой макет и в коде пытаетесь наполнить его виджетами. Это абсурд!

Comment: Т.е. сначала я в .kv перечисляю вообще все, что будет в приложении, желательно с id, после чего мне в питоне останется только написать функции для кнопок и т.п.? Я создал пустой макет и пытаюсь понять, как с ним работать. у меня есть главное окно, поделенное на две части, которые представлены boxlayout.Или я опять что-то путаю? Чуть больше конкретики, пожалуйста.

Comment: Конкретней нужно на простом примере показать...